# Is there any way to find neck position from the image (or live camera)?

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, face-detection

Not able to get exact neck position from the image.

Tried some face detection library but no one is providing exact neck position(they are providing eyes, jaw, mouth etc but not exact neck position).

Comment: `face detection library` should have nothing to do with `neck position`, as `neck` is not a part of the face, I think. If you want a library to do this - it is off-topic to ask for a library here. If you want to implement this - show some effort. In general - first think about how do you detect neck in real life, then implement it programmatically

Answer (score -1):

In simple way the coordinates for neck are:

```
eyesDistance = distance between both eye.
eyeNoseYDistance = distance between nose Y coord and average of both eye y coord
neck x1 = noseX - eyesDistance*0.65
neck x2 = noseX + eyesDistance * 0.65

neck y1 = y2 = noseY + eyeNoseYDistance * 2.15
```

Try to implement this in your code. I believe that this is initial stage but it will work. This is just a clue. After this you need to calculate angle of face with neck to calculate accurate neck position for each cases.